# How can I write a regex to find only numbers with four digits?

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to write a regex in Ruby to search a string for numbers of only four digits. I am using
`/\d{4}/` but this is giving me number with four and more digits.

Eg: "`12345-456-6575 some text  9897`"

In this case I want only `9897` and `6575` but I am also getting `1234` which has a length of five characters.

Comment: You can use this site to test your regular expression: [http://rubular.com/](http://rubular.com/) @Dogbert is right by the way, just tested his regex...

Comment: Should it match `1234` in `abcd1234efgh`?

Comment: You can use this site to test your regular expression:

http://rubular.com/

@Dogbert is right by the way, just tested his regex...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
"12345-456-6575 some text 9897".scan(/\b\d{4}\b/)
=> ["6575", "9897"]
```

Comment: The `\b` is handy since it will match beginning, end, or a word "breaking" character.

Answer (score 3):

Try matching on a word boundary (`\b`) on both sides of the four digit sequence:

```ruby
s = '12345-456-6575 some text 9897'
s.scan(/\b\d{4}\b/) # => ["6575", "9897"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add one more condition to your expression: the number can only be returned if there are 4 digits AND both the character before and after that 4-digit number must be a non-number.

Comment: What if there is no character before or after the number?

Answer (score 0):

or even more generally: anything but a digit before and/or after the four digits:

```
/\D\d{4}\D/
```

Comment: This grabs only the first occurrence of a 4 digit number.

Comment: This fails at the start and end of the string, and it fails when sequences of 4 digits are separated by one other character (like `1234-5678-9999`) because the `\D` needs to consume a character.

Comment: @AJC: In JavaScript, maybe. Not in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Try /[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]/

Comment: This fails at the end of the string, and it still matches five-digit numbers - it'll match `2345` in `12345-54321`.

Comment: @Tim, yes. It is wrong. Dogbert has a good one i think. Thanks for pointing out the error.

Answer (score -1):

You should specify a separator for the pattern. As in if the digits would be preceded and followed by a space the REGEX would `/\s\d{4}\s/`, hope that helps.

Comment: This is wrong. a) It fails on his example where the numbers are separated by dashes. b) It fails at the start and end of the string. c) It fails even with spaces as separators if there is only one space between numbers. Look at `a 1234 5678 b`: the second `\s` consumes the second space, so the next time the regex is applied, it fails because the regex engine is now at the start of the second number.